# Java CardLayout IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am making a game that uses a CardLayout to switch between four JPanels (gamePanel, startMenu, pauseMenu, and levelMenu). I'm getting the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout". However, I added all the cards to panel, which has the layout manager CardLayout, so I don't understand why panel wouldn't be the parent. I've looked at the Java tutorial for CardLayout as well as Stack Overflow questions that involve the IllegalArgumentException, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Game:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** Class Contains the main method and the game's logic */
public class Game {

    /** Field The JFrame for the game */
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    /** Field The JPanel that uses CardLayout to only display one JPanel at a time */
    private JPanel panel;

    /** Field The CardLayout that controls which JPanel is showing */
    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    /** Field The JPanel that displays the playing field */
    private JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();

    /** Field The first menu the player sees */
    private JPanel startMenu = new JPanel();

    /** Field The menu the player sees when the game is paused */
    private JPanel pauseMenu = new JPanel();

    /** Field The menu that allows the player to select which level to play */
    private JPanel levelMenu = new JPanel();

    /** Constructor for Game with no parameters */
    public Game() {
        initializeGame();
    }

    /** Main method of Game */
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new Game();
    }

    /** Sets up frame and panel */
    private void initializeGame() {
        panel = createPanel();

        panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();

        cardLayout.show(panel, "startMenu");
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        panel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        panel.add(startMenu, "startMenu");
        panel.add(pauseMenu, "pauseMenu");
        panel.add(levelMenu, "levelMenu");
        panel.add(gamePanel, "gamePanel");

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned the `panel` variable to two objects, one created by the `createPanel()` method and the other by obtaining the contentPane. One you add components to the GUI with, the other you call the show method on, and for this reason the JVM complains. The solution is not to do this, to assign only one object once to this variable.

To see what I mean, search your code for

```
 panel =
```

and see the lines that pop up.